# Angular2 router listen to parameter changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several links navigating as

```
http://localhost:4200/#/forward/services/our-services?category=1
http://localhost:4200/#/forward/services/our-services?category=2
http://localhost:4200/#/forward/services/our-services?category=3
```

I would like to fetch the value of category

Ive tried

```
this.sub = this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {

  this.category = + params['category'];

  console.log(params['category']);

});
```

The console.log() is only printend once ,

How can i ensure i capture whenever the value of category changes

This is what am using for navigation

```
<ul id="menu-services-menu" class="menu" *ngFor="let category of categories">
 <li><a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/forward/services/our-services']" [queryParams]="{ category: category.category }" >{{category.category}}</a></li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: You want the changes in queryParams, not in params. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#queryParams-anchor

Comment: awesome query params works

Comment: what of the routerLinkActive class always remains active even when the params change

Answer (score 4):

```
constructor(router:Router, route:ActivatedRoute) {
  router.events
  filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd) 
  .forEach(e => console.log(route.snapshot.params['category']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also with Angular 2 (Angular 5 as of this writing) do this:

```
constructor(private router:Router) {
 router.events.subscribe(data=>{
   if(data instanceof ActivationEnd){
     this.category = data.snapshot.params['category'];
   }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subscribing the route.events and then have to check or filter the events is possible to subscribe the specific queryParams and just get the params. I think is a more clean solution for this problem.
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route
  .queryParams
  .subscribe(params => {
    this.page = params['category'];
  });
}
```